# Como funciona a pilha (stack) do jQuery?

Tags: jquery, api, stack

Quando aprendi a usar o método [`.end`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) do jQuery, percebi que era uma ferramenta poderosa que garante muita expressividade ao código (e já fui logo vendo [como integrá-la aos meus plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9154550/520779)). Embora eu tenha um conhecimento básico do seu funcionamento:

```
$(meuSeletor)       // Seleciona um conjunto de elemtentos   [meuSeletor]
    .fazAlgo()      // Faz algo com ele, mantém o conjunto   [meuSeletor]
    .find(sub)      // Acha um subconjunto, mas empilha o anterior [sub, meuSeletor]
        .fazAlgo()  // Faz algo com esse subconjunto               [sub, meuSeletor]
    .end()          // "Desempilha": volta o que tinha antes [meuSeletor]
    .fazAlgo();     // Faz algo com o conjunto original      [meuSeletor]
```

Algumas funções como o [`andSelf`](http://api.jquery.com/andSelf/) e o [`addBack`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) ainda me intrigam (lembro de há muito tempo ter tentado usar o `andSelf` na prática, mas não teve o resultado esperado). Gostaria que alguém explicasse, de forma simples e sucinta, como funciona esse sistema de empilhamento do jQuery, e como isso pode nos beneficiar (na autoria de plugins, por exemplo).

Comment: A dúvida é sobre o sistema de empilhamento em si, ou sobre o addBack?

Comment: @bfavaretto É sobre o sistema de empilhamento em si (o `addBack`, acabei de ver aqui que ele é semelhante ao `addSelf` - agora obsoleto). É fácil ver na API o que cada método individual faz, mas me falta a visão do todo. Achei que seria interessante perguntar aqui, em vez de ficar testando caso por caso tudo o que vier na minha cabeça (ex.: se eu fizer `addBack` depois `end`, o que será que acontece? se eu fizer `pushStack` e no objeto original eu fizer `end`, o que será que acontece? etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Olhei o [código-fonte](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js) é mais simples do que eu pensava. A pilha foi implementada como uma cadeia de objetos. Cada objeto jQuery pode ter uma propriedade `prevObject`, apontando para o objeto anterior. Portanto:

```
var o = $(meuSeletor);
var sub = o.find(sub);
sub.prevObject === o; // true
```

O [`end`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L110) retorna o `prevObject`, ou um objeto jQuery vazio (acho):

```
end: function() {
    return this.prevObject || this.constructor(null);
}
```

O [`pushStack`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L66) cria um novo objeto com os elementos passados e o próprio objeto que o invocou, e define o `prevObject` como esse último:

```
pushStack: function( elems ) {

    // Build a new jQuery matched element set
    var ret = jQuery.merge( this.constructor(), elems );

    // Add the old object onto the stack (as a reference)
    ret.prevObject = this;
    ret.context = this.context;

    // Return the newly-formed element set
    return ret;
}
```

O `addBack` cria um novo objeto, adicionando o `prevObject` ao atual (obrigado ao Gabriel Santos por localizar o código):

```
addBack: function(selector) { 
    return this.add(selector == null ? this.prevObject : this.prevObject.filter(selector)); 
}
```

Comment: Tem razão, parece bem simples. Fiz um único teste com o `addBack`, e parece que ele é uma "operação destrutiva" como qualquer outra (i.e. `$('#meuDiv').siblings().addBack().end()` volta pros irmãos; para voltar ao elemento original, precisaria de mais um `.end()`). Amanhã volto nessa pergunta.

Comment: ``addBack: function(selector) {
return this.add(selector == null ? this.prevObject : this.prevObject.filter(selector)); }``

Answer (score 0):

É bem simples na verdade, as funções de seleção, retornam o próprio elemento, assim você pode usar o chamado encadeamento para dar uma continuidade natural no script.

É como fazer algo assim:

```
$.fn.test = function() {
    return this.each(function(){/* faz algo com cada elemento*/});
};
```

O uso ficaria assim: `$('div').test();`

E você poderia continuar pegando os parágrafos filhos por exemplo:

```
$('div').test().find('p');
```

Assim quando você utiliza de uma função que retorna um nó, ela executa seu escopo e retorna o mesmo nó para que continue sendo usando... É como se você caminhasse pelo DOM.

Aqui você chega até o elemento `li` e adiciona uma classe:

```
$('li').addClass('test');
```

Aqui do mesmo ponto em que parou, você pode subir até a lista elemento pai do item de lista atual e executar outra ação, como esconder por exemplo:

```
$('li').addClass('test').closest('ul').hide();
```

Isso diminui a escrita e melhora consideravelmente a performance em certos scripts.

Se quiser ver como um plugin faz isso por dentro você pode ver os padrões desenvolvidos pelo Addy Osmani da Google, eu inclusive contribui neste aqui: [Best Options](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-patterns/blob/master/patterns/jquery.best.options.plugin-boilerplate.js)

Comment: Valeu pela resposta, mas acho que você interpretou mal a pergunta: não estou me referindo ao encadeamento simples, mas sim quando o jQuery "lembra" da última seleção e permite você voltar a ela depois. No seu último exemplo, você poderia fazer `...hide().end().addClass('foo');` e **os `li`s** - não a `ul` - ficariam com a classe `foo` [além de `test`].

Comment: @mgibsonbr Entendi, então, na verdade o jQuery quando retorna para você um conjunto de nós, ele não retorna exatamente nós, ele retorna um objeto que ele mesmo gera, e neste objeto ele guarda além de os verdadeiros nós em um índice, esse "empilhamento" que é passado de uma função para outra, assim quando a função do encadeamento pega o objeto retornado pela função anterior ela sabe por quais seletores passou, e consegue fazer o caminho inverso por exemplo. Não vou me recordar qual o índice em que ele guarda já que é de pouca utilidade, mas se eu recordar comento aqui.

Comment: Espero que eu tenha entendido agora rsrs ^^

Comment: Sim, é mais ou menos isso que você falou. Tem nuances, é claro, daí a razão da pergunta (i.e. para que alguém com mais experiência possa explicar direitinho como funciona).